# Remove class after adding / Restart CSS animation onClick in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I'm using `CSS transform` to animate an AwesomeFont icon when I click it

```
.animate {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: animation
}
```

AFAIK, to trigger the animation I need to add the above class to an element after it's being rendered. So I do this in React

```
class Class extends Component {
  state = {
    likes: 5,
    play: false
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState((p) => { return {play: p.play ? false : true}; })
  }

  render() {
    <a onClick={this.handleClick} href="#" />
      <Icon className={this.state.play ? 'animate' : ''} name="thumbs-up" />
      {this.state.likes}
    </a>
  }
}
```

which works pretty well if I'm just toggling the states with each click, but now I want to trigger the animation on every click

```
...

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState((p) => { return {play: p.play ? false : true}; })
  }

  render() {
    <a onClick={this.handleClick} onMouseUp={() => this.setState(()=>{return {play:false}; })} href="#" />
      <Icon className={this.state.play ? 'animate' : ''} name="thumbs-up" />
      {this.state.likes}
    </a>
  }
}
```

It's not pretty, but I just want to illustrate a point, and I don't think it is working as it should because clicking on the number part of the link repeatedly doesn't trigger the animation but clicking the `Icon` does.

I tried adding the class `onMouseDown` and removing it `onMouseUp` but React just batches up the `setStates`, resulting in nothing. Anyone with any ideas how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change a tag to div tag. The click and other mouse events work fine on div and it's child elements. See an example:

```
<div id='wrapper' onClick='wrapperClick()' onMouseUp='wrapperMouseUp()'>
  This is parent
  <div id='child'>
    I am child
  </div>
</div>


#wrapper {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#child {
  padding-top:10px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

function wrapperClick() {
  alert('you clicked me')
}

function wrapperMouseUp() {
  alert('Mouse Up')
}
```

Just note that mouse up fires before click event.

```
handleMouseUp = () => {
  setCounter()
}
handleClick = () => {
  setCounter()
}

setCounter() {
  this.setState((p) => { return {play: p.play ? false : true}; })
}

  render() {
    <div onClick={this.handleClick} onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp} href="#" />
      <Icon className={this.state.play ? 'animate' : ''} name="thumbs-up" />
      {this.state.likes}
    </div>
  }
}
```